# Logging with same format as Jetty

Tags: logging, clojure, jetty

I have a clojure app set up using compojure to do REST api goodness. When I start up the app using `lein ring server` or `run-jetty` I get the following output to the console:

```
2013-07-01 22:11:48.610:INFO:oejs.Server:jetty-7.x.y-SNAPSHOT
2013-07-01 22:11:48.640:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:3000
```

I would like to log other info messages about the startup of the app to the console, but for the life of my I can't figure out how to use the same utility being used to generate those messages. I'm sure I could copy it manually myself using tools.clojure.logging, but that seems hacky. Does anyone know what functions ring is using internally that I could then import and use?

EDIT

Jeremy pointed me in the right direction, but I still can't get anything to actually show up, although all methods appear to return successfully:

```
(import 'org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Log)
(def logger (Log/getLogger "mylog"))
(.debug logger (Throwable. "foo"))
```

This *ought* to output something to stderr, but it never does. Can anyone provide any help?

Answer (score 1):

Those logs statements are coming from Jetty. The "oejs" is short for `org.eclipse.jetty.server`. You can see how the first log statement is logged [here](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/master/jetty-server/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/server/Server.java#L284). If you continue to trace where the logger came from, you'll eventually get to [`Log.java`](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/master/jetty-util/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/util/log/Log.java). You can probably initiate a logger the same way.

Comment: I finally got to testing out the Log class, and it doesn't work for me. I've updated my question above, do you have any ideas?

Comment: What happens if you pass `nil` into `Log/getLogger`? The source code I referred you to says that passing in null/nil will give you the default logger. Anything else you pass in will try looking up a logger by that name, and I'm guessing "mylog" isn't one of them.

Comment: In that case I get a `More than one matching method found` exception. Which is weird. But I also tried the `getRootLogger` method which appears to also return the default logger, and that still doesn't output anything.